# (Java) modifying public static variables

Tags: java, constructor, static, private, public

kinda new here.

Anyways, I'm relatively new to Java, these are some practice questions from uni, I have one question. 
How do I make it so that TOTAL_RESERVES can't be modified by an outside. Right now if I say

Gold.TOTAL_RESERVES = 500;

That changes the value of it.
How do I make it so only the constructor changes the value.

I know I can make it private but I want it to be in the API.

Here's the reference API

http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2014-15/W/1030/sectionZ/hw/doc/Gold/index.html

```
public class Gold
{
    static int TOTAL_RESERVES = 100;
    private int weight;

    public Gold (int weight)
    {
        TOTAL_RESERVES -= weight;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getWeight()
    {
        return this.weight;
    }

    public static int remaining()
    {
        return TOTAL_RESERVES;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return "Weight = " + this.weight;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If there is one field in the entire universe that I would make private it is `Gold.TOTAL_RESERVES.`

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too but the API displays it (have had to do Javadoc as well), so it is public. =/

It is okay to document private variables? It seems wrong. xD

Comment: @Nesan Why did you make it static?

Comment: Use `final` and make it a constant

Comment: Mainly because it said in the API it was static.

@TheUknown Then I can't modify it later when the constructor is called. =/

Comment: I'm not sure if anything of that kind exists. If its `private` it will be accessible to entire `class` and `final` will not allow it to be changed. May be you should update your question with some more explanation of what the API needs etc. Especially the part "I want it to be in the API"(what do you mean by that)?

Comment: Oh, sorry if I wasn't clear about that part. We're also doing Javadoc and if it's private it shouldn't show up in the API.

public static final int TOTAL_RESERVES 

is what it says in the documentation. Now I'm starting to this it's a mistake. I'll e-mail the professor about it (and get back), thank you for your help everyone.

Comment: @Nesan in the API specified the declaration clearly: "public static final int TOTAL_RESERVES", so why do you want changing that declaration ?

Comment: To keep track of how much gold is mined, but you're right I can't touch that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the API you specified, your code should look something like:

```
public class Gold {

    public static final int TOTAL_RESERVES = 100;

    private int weight;

    private static int remainingWeight;

    static {
        remainingWeight = TOTAL_RESERVES;
    }

    public Gold(int weight) {

        if (remainingWeight <= 0) {

            this.weight = 0;
            remainingWeight = 0;
        }

        else {
            if (weight >= 0) {
                if (weight > remaining())
                    this.weight = remaining();
                else
                    this.weight = weight;
            } else {
                this.weight = 0;
            }

            remainingWeight -= this.weight;
        }
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return this.weight;
    }

    public static int remaining() {
        return remainingWeight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Weight = " + this.weight;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Comment: But won't remaining() always return 100?

Comment: Hey, thanks for this!

BTW, what exactly does

 static {
        remainingWeight = TOTAL_RESERVES;
    } 

do? New syntax to me.

Comment: @Nesan its a static initialization block, you can learn more from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 0):

I honestly would say making it private is the best solution to this problem. Its not the answer you want...But its the best solution.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too but the API displays it (have had to do Javadoc as well), so it is public. =/

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, the field detail for `TOTAL_RESERVES` is `public static final int TOTAL_RESERVES`. The `final` modifier means that `TOTAL_RESERVES` is a constant. To keep track of the current reserves you would need to create another variable, like this:

```
private static int CURRENT_RESERVES = TOTAL_RESERVES;
```

And use it to subtract the weight and return the remaining reserves.

Comment: Yes, this seems like the most plausible solution.  
I guess doing this whole thing with one field is impossible.
Thanks!
I'll  check with the professor tomorrow.